# Cloudfront Distribution S3 logging not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-cloudfront

I have set up a cloudfront distribution one year ago... and I had s3 logging enabled on it, and linked an s3 bucket named "cloudfront-s3".

- Now I went back to check, and saw that the logs are not being sent to that bucket at all.
- I cannot seem to find the problem or cause of WHY this is happening.
- Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We had the same problem with the same "fix" . It would be nice to find out the root cause to prevent it from happening again

Comment: The root cause _may_ have been that the CloudFront ACL had been removed from the bucket. If it happens again, under the bucket's Permissions tab in the S3 console, check that the account with canonical ID `c4c1ede66af53448b93c283ce9448c4ba468c9432aa01d700d3878632f77d2d0` (CloudFront logs) is still listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, by disabling logging on the cloudfront distribution and then again enabling it back again.

Answer (score 0):

The following Terraform will re-enable the ACL for CloudFront:

```
data aws_cloudfront_log_delivery_canonical_user_id current {}
data aws_canonical_user_id current {}


resource aws_s3_bucket access_logs {
  bucket = "my-access-logs"
}

resource aws_s3_bucket_acl access_logs {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.access_logs.id

  access_control_policy {
    grant {
      grantee {
        id   = data.aws_cloudfront_log_delivery_canonical_user_id.current.id
        type = "CanonicalUser"
      }
      permission = "FULL_CONTROL"
    }
    owner {
      id = data.aws_canonical_user_id.current.id
    }
  }
}
```

I ran into this issue after updating my Terraform `aws_s3_bucket` resource to replace the deprecated `logging`, `versioning`, etc... attributes.  Unfortunately, I didn't notice it until long after I made the update.

The [`cloudfront_log_delivery_canonical_user_id`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudfront_log_delivery_canonical_user_id) documentation is a good reference.